# Shisha Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and six?

### ?שישה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 306.

And that which can be classified as lazy gematria, you must shoo away.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and five entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: "And that which". `:-)`

Comment: @msh210 I knew I could count on you to figure that one out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.partnersintorah.org/jewish-holidays/roshhashana

> FROM THE CHASIDIC MASTERS The Hebrew word for honey is, “Dvash.” The
>   numerical equivalent of this word is 306, which is the same as the
>   words, “Av Harachamim” [Our father of mercy], and evokes Hashem’s
>   compassion for his children.

[Bnei Yissochor](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14491&st=&pgnum=116) says that Kisleiv = 306 when spelled out as follows כף סמך למד וו. This is the same as "Av Harachamim". Although he says that he will elaborate further I have been unable to find where he does.

Answer (score 8):

Both *Ishah* (as אשה) and *Devash* (דבש) have a *Gematria* of 306.

Even though I found, through Google, a lot of positive mention of the equality between *Ishah* and *Devash* (even [one](http://www.inner.org/healing/healing36.htm), at the bottom of the page, who claims Kabalistic importance of the equality), none gave sources.

The one reference I did find, is from [Midrash Rabeinu Bahye for Vayiqra 2:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14129&pgnum=9), s.v. *Ki Khol She'or ve-Khol Devash Lo Taqtiru mi-Menu Isheh la-Shem*:

> ודבש ג"כ יצר הרע כי דב״ש
> בגימטריא אשה והאשה היא יצה״ר. כי כן מצינו
> בארם הראשון כשחטא אמר(בראשית ג) האשה אשר
> נתתה מעמדי. רצה לומר יצר הרע שיצרח בי. והאשה
> אמרה הנחש השיאני וזה סוד נחש והאשה והאיבה

In my translation:

> And Honey is *Yetzer ha-Ra* for *Devash* (דבש) in *Gematria* is *Ishah* (אשה) and the *Ishah* is *Yetzer ha-Ra*. For we find in *Adam ha-Rishon* when he sinned he said (Bereshit 3:12) 'the *Ishah* which you gave with me', meaning to say 'the *Yetzer ha-Ra* that you created in me'. And the *Ishah* said 'the *Nachash* tricked me', and this is the *Sod* of *Nachash* and the *Ishah* and the enmity.