# Calling one's wife 'honey'

Tags: sources-mekorot, gematria-numerology

I recently heard that calling one's wife 'honey' is a Jewish concept born from the fact that the gematriot are the same.

דבש = 306.
אשה = 306.

Does anyone talk about this? Or is this a convenient coincidence?

Comment: I would put my money on coincidence.

Comment: Do Jews call their wifes dvash?

Comment: Some Jewish wives are called Dvoshe

Comment: Related: "[Shisha Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22022/1368)"

Comment: I can tell you a rabbi who taught me said this, but I don't know where he got it from.